# How can I add a dropdown list in YII bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView

Tags: gridview, yii, updates

How can I add a dropdown list in YII bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView.

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',  array(
    'id'=>'customer-grid',
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'surname',
        'name',
        'middlename',
        'dateOfBirth',
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{add}',
            'buttons'=>array(
                'add' => array(
                    'label'=>'list-box',
                    'icon'=>'plus',
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("url")',
                    'options'=>array(
                        'class'=>'btn btn-small',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

I just want to add a drop down list instead of "add" button here . can anybody help me. am very new to YII

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of putting dropdown in tbbutton column put it in column itself as shown

Include a function in your model as

```
public function getDropdown()
{
    $values = array(
        1 => 'value1',
        2 => 'value2',

    );
    return CHtml::dropDownlist('$model',variable,$values, array(
        'class'     => 'values',
        'data-id'   => $this->id,
    ));
}
```

And in cgrid view Call the function as

```
'columns'=>array(
 'surname',
    'name',
    'middlename',
    'dateOfBirth',
     array(
            'name'  => 'Value',
            'type'  => 'raw',
            'value' => '$data->Dropdown',
        ),
),
```

Comment: is it like  'add' => array
            ( 'name'  => 'Value',
        'type'  => 'raw',
        'value' => '$data->Dropdown',
    ),..? am I correct

Comment: but in your example, we define function as "getDropdown()" and we call the function as 'value' => '$data->Dropdown',..can you please tell me why..Thank you...

Comment: No i had suggested u the standard way of getter meyhod u can directly put CHtml::dropDownlist('') directly to value attribute of cgridview i.e $value=>CHtml::dropDownlist('');